# Cannot access grub or boot from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, freeze

I have been plagued by the following for over a month and at a loss for other ways of asking Google how best to troubleshoot.

#### Background:

Had been running Ubuntu 18.04 smoothly for many months on a machine with new hardware.

Decided to install win10 (unsure of the version#) for gaming/steam compatibility. Was able to boot to win10 desktop on first try, from there began configuring/updating then proceeded to join the Microsoft beta first look program or whatever it's called. Sorry for the lack of detail. I have been using Linux/Ubuntu on all my desktops/laptops for years now and this is my first attempt of getting back into windows.

#### Problem:

Once I finish steps of signing up for beta program, a restart was required. That was the last time I have seen the desktop.

**Every time I reboot, the process freezes right before the login screen**.
I have tried reconfiguring bios, clearing cmos, removing mb battery, booting from live USB with win10 on it and Ubuntu (many different distros). **never make it to the login screen. After the delay to enter bios, depending on the os im booting to, the theme will change correctly and then freeze**

I have not been able to find a way to access the grub menu or boot into a terminal and would appreciate any advice on doing that specifically as well as any other ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Issues can arise with insider preview specially if you chose the fast one. Why did you sign p for it anyway? In which OS do you get stuck? Windows or Ubuntu? If you can't access grub how do you change OS? Also please reply with @username

Comment: @Simon Sudler thank you quick response. I was running Ubuntu initially for many years. Followed steps to dual boot win10 on top of Ubuntu. I successfully booted to win10 desktop on the first try, but that was the only time since I subsequently signed up for insider program (ty for providing the correct name). Since then I have been unable to boot into either previously installed os and have also been unable to boot using any type of os via a live USB.

Comment: @Simon I figure if I'm able to open a terminal I would be ok but I've only been able to get into the bios via pressing F2 or DEL. Shift, ESC, etc doesn't work. Oh and unless I override boot and select a specific device to boot from, it defaults to attempting to boot win10. After the asus logo splash screen and delay for F2/DEL inputs, the win10 dot-loading circle appears and quickly freezes.

Comment: @OrianKelley I did not respond, I just made some formatting to your post...

Comment: @OrianKelley If you have more details on your problem, please edit our post and add theme there.

Comment: My system...MB: asus rog-strix b450-f
Cpu: amd ryzen 5 3400g w/ vega 11 graphics 
Ram: vanguard 16gb 3600
Gpu: asus Nvidia GeForce 1060 3gb

Comment: Sounds like a UEFI issue... have you tried to disable UEFI boot?

Comment: @simon ok sorry. First time posting lol